# incompatible types

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, backend

Estoy creando la clase encargada de la seguridad de mi proyecto, al crear un método publica que debería construir el usuario con sus respectivos roles.

> 

```
 public static UsuarioPrincipal build(Usuario usuario){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
        authorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) usuario.getRoles().stream()
                .map(rol -> new 
      SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getRolNombre().name())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Tengo un error en la siguiente linea:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

El error que me salta es el siguiente:

```
incompatible types: List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> cannot be converted to List<GrantedAuthority>;
```

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: agrea los imports de tu archivo, uno de ellos debe ser incorrecto. Saludos.

Comment: No deberias apliar cast, `map` se esta encargando de crear objetos de la clase `SimpleGrantedAuthority` a partir del nombre obtenido de los objetos  en la lista `usuarios.getroles();` deberia ir asi `authorities = usuario.getRoles().stream()
                .map(rol -> new 
      SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getRolNombre().name())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: El error es básico cuando trabajas con genéricos. Estás intentando asignar a una variable de tipo  `List<GrantedAuthority>` un objeto de tipo `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>`. OJO, aunque `SimpleGrantedAuthority` implemente `GrantedAuthority` NO significa que una Lista de `SimpleGrantedAuthority`  sea una lista de `GrantedAuthority`. Ten claro que el tipo `List<GrantedAuthority>`  ni hereda ni implementa el tipo  `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>`, por lo que NO puedes asignarlo como si hubiera una cadena de herencia.¿Solución? Declara tu variable authorities del tipo `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>`.

Comment: Costó pero quedo claro. Muchas gracias, voy a implementarlo.